# Resize TableCell on select/deselect

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I'm new to iOS and MonoTouch, and I have a pretty basic need - I have two vastly different views to display in the same table cell depending on whether it is selected or not. When you load the app I'll present a list of products in a custom UITableView, with all the rows deselected and each row basically just showing the product names in a label. As soon as a user taps one of the rows and selects it, I show a very different view with more of a shopping cart layout. Since the two views are so different they have vastly different sizes. What i need is for the cell itself (or row?) to grow and shrink according to the natural height of whichever view is currently being displayed.

I'm using descendants of UITableViewController, UITableViewSource, and UITableViewCell for the solution. What I do is add both versions to the cell's ContentView, then set the Hidden property as needed when the cell/row is selected/deselected to show the right layout. That works well. I'm in demo mode right now, so I'm not overly worried about efficiency or responsiveness, that will have to come later.

I know that GetHeightForRow is responsible for sizing the rows but it only gets called once, when the cell is first shown. It seems to me that I need to alert the TableView to re-poll the source for a new size as the views are changing, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I tried (rather hopefully) to cause GetHeightForRow to be invoked again manually using Cell.SetNeedsLayout and Cell.SetNeedsDisplay, hoping that would cause the table to re-query the source for new dimensions, but no joy.

I tinkered with the direct approach, trying to size the contentview itself but it didn't seem as if it was leading anywhere. I feel as if the table needs to be told to query for a new row size, but I'm open to any suggestions.

Surely I'm not the first to attempt this?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try forcing `GetHeightForRow` to be called again by calling [ReloadRows](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=M%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UITableView.ReloadRows%28MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath%5B%5D,MonoTouch.UIKit.UITableViewRowAnimation%29) instead.

You may or may not have to specify begin/end updates (this might just be for animation, though?)

```
tableView.BeginUpdates();
tableView.EndUpdates();
```

Comment: That was the missing piece, thanks so much. My one complaint is that after the reload call the selected state seems to be lost; if my cell was selected before being reloaded it no longer is afterwards. But that was an easy fix and its also possible that's an issue I've created somehow. Anyway, this has me much closer to the end goal.

Comment: Glad it helped. It most likely fires GetCell again - you have to keep the state of the cell stored to reload the checkmark status there. Same thing happens if you scroll a checked item off screen and back on.